# System keeps booting into recovery after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: partition, macos

I have (had) Maverics running under VMWare Workstation 12. Sadly I decided to upgrade to El Capitan. Now my system always boots into recovery (located at "/Volumes/OS X Base System"). I tried reinstalling Mac OS there but it keeps booting into this

[image]

What should I do to boot from /Volumes/Macintosh ? I tried selecting "Startup Disk" but it still boots into recovery :(

Answer (score 1):

Try booting it into Recovery and use Disk Utility to verify the disk it see if we have any problems there.

Hold these keys until the Apple logo appears. After your computer finishes starting up, you should see a desktop with an OS X menu bar and an OS X Utilities window with the options listed above. If you see a login window or your own desktop instead of the Utilities window, it's possible that you didn't press Command-R early enough. Restart your computer and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was resolved by deleting "/Volumes/OS X Base System". Aparently it forced loader to boot into whatever is available.